# apache2.4 + php-fpm + squirrelmail

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, squirrelmail

I'm trying to make squirrelmail work with apache 2.4 + php-fpm (via mod_proxy_fcgi), I want it to work on all virtual hosts when requesting "/wm". On my old VPS, which had apache2.2 and php as its module it was achieved with next:

```
Alias /wm /usr/share/squirrelmail
<Directory /usr/share/squirrelmail>
RemoveHandler .php  .php3 .php4 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php  .php3 .php4 .phtml
php_admin_value open_basedir none
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /tmp
php_admin_value session.save_path "/tmp"
php_admin_value include_path .:..
php_admin_value safe_mode off
php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
DirectoryIndex index.php       
</Directory>
```

I tried ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:1302/usr/share/squirrelmail/$1 but alas apache doesn't allow ProxyPassMatch with directory directive. I kept on experimenting and only "File not found" and "No input file specified" (I assume these are messages from php-fpm since at least 404 error is customized for apache). As of now, I totally don't know what to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, kinda dirty solution but it worked so I'll just post it here in case someone needs it. 

What I did to make it work was:

1. I created symlink in the root folder of virtual host.

 2. Added `/usr/share/squirrelmail/:/etc/squirrelmail/:/var/lib/squirrelmail/:/etc/hostname:/etc/mailname` to open_basedir for pools that were handling these virtual hosts.

Note: Follow symlink option must be on (it's on by default I think)

 Hope this helps someone as temporary solution.